# Unable to compare database schema in Visual Studio 2022 due to exception

Tags: visual-studio, exception, compare, schema

I recently got a new laptop and installed Visual Studio 2022 on it. I am trying to compare schema for an SQL Server database project in my solution, but every time I try to select a source or destination, the connection window does not appear. Instead, I'm greeted with an exception window.
For the life of me, I have been unable to fix this. I have never faced this issue ever in any of the versions of Visual Studio. I have tried repairing and reinstalling Visual Studio 2022, but to no avail. I couldn't find any specific solutions to this problem online.
Can someone guide me in the right direction?

The exception is as below:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SharedUtilities.ProjectUtilities.GetGuidOfProject(IVsHierarchy projectNode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareConnectionDialog.PopulateProjectCombos()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareConnectionDialog..ctor(Boolean isSource, ISchemaCompareParticipant participant)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareSourceTargetControl.CollectFromConnectionDialog(Boolean isSource)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareSourceTargetControl.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommittedInternal(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: I also get this.  What works for me though is closing all VS instances, and restarting VS. I cannot promise it will work for everyone. If you can, please vote for this bug report here so Micorosft can see that it affects multiple users: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SQL-Schema-Comparison-Crash/10349368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it appears to be a bug in either VS or with SSDT. Issue logged here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SQL-Schema-Comparison-Crash/10349368

In the mean-time, while Microsoft is working on a fix, you can check that the SQL Database project is targeting the latest .NET Framework (4.8), and also make sure .NET framework SDK and tools  are installed as part of your VS workloads...

[image: VS Installer]

Open the project file in a text editor and change the value for the `TargetFrameworkVersion` property to `v4.8`. Save and then reload the project/solution (possibly a restart of VS may be required).

Comment: Thanks, for commenting and for providing the possible solution. I will try this on Monday at work and let you know.
Meanwhile, I have added my comment on the thread that you linked above.

Comment: Guess what, it worked! I updated my SQL project to 4.8 and the dialog box started opening. I already had the 4.8 targeting pack installed.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AhmadZaib if an answer helped you solve a problem, please vote for and accept it. thanks.

Comment: According to Microsoft, the issue has been fixed in Visual Studio. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SQL-Schema-Comparison-Crash/10349368#T-N10434268 I can confirm that it is working at least from Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.1, if not earlier.